# Getx fetch changes of variables

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-state

I have a getx Controller. In it i have declared two variables, which will be updated

```
var percentageEVS = 0.obs;
 var percentOthers =0.obs;
```

Im trying to change the values of these variables using the following function

```
  calculatespentTime(){
    final totalDuration = dashboard[0].duration??0;
    final durationEVS = dashboard[1].duration!.toInt();
     final _percentageEVS = (durationEVS/totalDuration)*100;
     percentageEVS.value = _percentageEVS.toInt() ;
}
```

How ever I'm not getting the changed values

```
        final List<ChartData> chartData = [
      ChartData(x: 'Maths', y:_controller.percentageEVS.value.toDouble(), color: Colors.red),
      ChartData(x: 'English', y: 38, color: Colors.blue),
]
```

How can i get the changed value and pass it to chartData??

Comment: have you tried using `Obx` Widget ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
ChartData(x: 'Maths', y:_controller.percentageEVS.value.toDouble(), color: Colors.red)
```

to

```
Obx(()=>ChartData(x: 'Maths', y:_controller.percentageEVS.value.toDouble(), color: Colors.red))
```